# PHP Vertical Table Experiment

Tags: php, mysql

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Nov 03, 2017 at 02:26 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `tobedev`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tb_product`
--

CREATE TABLE `tb_product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `price` double(12,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tb_product`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_product` (`id`, `name`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'Product 1', 100.00),
(2, 'Product 2', 100.00),
(3, 'Product 3', 100.00),
(4, 'Product 4', 100.00),
(5, 'Product 5', 100.00),
(6, 'Product 6', 100.00),
(7, 'Product 7', 100.00),
(8, 'Product 8', 100.00),
(9, 'Product 9', 100.00),
(10, 'Product 10', 100.00),
(11, 'Product 11', 100.00),
(12, 'Product 12', 100.00),
(13, 'Product 13', 100.00),
(14, 'Product 14', 100.00),
(15, 'Product 15', 100.00);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tb_product`
--
ALTER TABLE `tb_product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tb_product`
--
ALTER TABLE `tb_product`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=16;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Hey Guy's is there anybody  can help me to fix the error? i'm new in php
here is the code.

when i tried to run it, it's gave me error like 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'no' in D:\xampp\htdocs\vertical\index.php on line 61

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\vertical\index.php on line 61

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in D:\xampp\htdocs\vertical\index.php on line 62

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\vertical\index.php on line 62

Warning: Illegal string offset 'price' in D:\xampp\htdocs\vertical\index.php on line 63

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\vertical\index.php on line 63

i still can't figured out the problem, cause the website i took the code is in thailand language

```html
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'ACCDBMS17';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tobedev', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, price FROM tb_product LIMIT 14");
$stm->execute();

$no        = 1;
$data     = array();
while($result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $result['no'] = $no++;
    $data[] = $result;
}
$stm = null;
//echo '<pre>',print_r($data,true), '</pre>';

$count         = count($data); //หาจำนวนข้อมูลทั้งหมด
$row_num     = 5; //กำหนดจำนวนแถวที่ต้องการ
$col_num     = ceil($count/$row_num); //จำนวนคอลัมน์ที่จะแสดง


//สร้างอาร์เรย์ชุดใหม่
$new_data = array();
for($i=0;$i<$row_num;$i++) //วนลูปตามจำนวนแถวที่ต้องการ
{
    $row = array();
    $index = $i;
    for($j=0;$j<$col_num;$j++) //วนลูปตามจำนวนคอลัมน์ที่คำนวณได้
    {
        $row[] = isset($data[$index]) ? $data[$index] : '';
        $index += $row_num;//เลื่อนลำดับข้อมูลของคอลัมน์ต่อไป
    }
    $new_data[] = $row;
}
//echo '<pre>',print_r($new_data,true), '</pre>';

//สร้างตารางข้อมูล
echo '<table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspaceing=1>';

echo '<tr>';
for($i=0;$i<$col_num;$i++) //วนลูปตามจำนวนคอลัมน์ที่คำนวณได้
{
    echo "<th>No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>";
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($new_data as $row) //วนลูปแสดงข้อมูลในอาร์เรย์ชุดใหม่ทีละแถว
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $data) //แสดงอาร์เรย์แต่ละชุด
    {
        echo "<td style='background-color:#eeeeee'>$data[no]</td>
        <td>$data[name]</td>
        <td>$data[price]</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';

$dbh = null;
?>
```

Comment: you don't have a column called `no`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your **no** key is simply not initialized. 
If you want to use it, you have to declare variable 
`$result = array('no'=>1, 'anotherno'=>2, 'etc'=>3);`
then you will be able to access $result['no'] but if try to access it 
$result['no'] = 1 you will get illegal string offset error